# Import csv file with date and observations correctly

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I am trying to import a csv file where each line looks likes this:

```
yyyy-mm-dd 0000
```

zeros are a placeholder for the number of observations

first line starts with the following:

```
date "obersvations"
```

I imported it via

```
obs <- read.csv("C:/adress/file.csv", sep=" ", header=TRUE, quote="\"", colClasses=c("Date",NA), as.is=TRUE)
```

if I take a look at the table in R the dates are not stored as a variable but rather as line names. Also the observations seam to be stored in a column called "date..observations". So how can I store the date as its own variable to do my basic plotting and regression analysis? Additionally, why does R take that weirdly composed name as the name for the variable observations?

Comment: R generally does not like spaces in variable names, thus the added "..".  If there is no separator (i.e. the ,) between the data column and observations, then you should use the more generic `read.delim()` instead of `read.csv()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Nonetheless, I fear that there is absolutely no difference between `read.delim()` and `read.csv()` in this case.

Comment: Must be something wrong in your real data. I just constructed a csv file as you describe and ran the command you gave and it works fine - two columns, first one a date.

Comment: Had a thought - is it possible that the 'space' between `date` and `"obversations"` is actually a non-breaking space? Try just editing the file and replacing it with a real space and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: What does `cat(readLines("C:/adress/file.csv", 10), sep="\n")` return? That may make it easier to diagnose the problem. Paste the result into your question as code (not into a comment which will concatenate the separate lines).

Comment: Thank you guys, I found smh a solution by removing the quotation marks from ´"obersvations"´.